# Loud pop on shutdown/reboot

Tags: 12.04, sound, xubuntu, alsa, speakers

Everytime I shut my computer down or reboot it there is a very loud pop/crack from the speakers. It sounds dangerous, like they are going to blow up. Is there a way to automatically mute the volume on shutdown?

Answer (score 4):

The popping is not a result of your computer not being muted; it's probably a result of capacitor discharge being sent to your speakers.

From what you've said, it sounds like you have a set of external speakers? If this is the case, turn them off before booting down; this will prevent any discharge from being amplified, and therefore being heard.

Comment: In my case, clicking doesn't occur when shutting down Windows, only when shutting down Ubuntu. Of course, the cause of the click is physical - capacitor or spark, but the pre-cause is possible the disgraceful shutting down of the sound card.

Comment: This is common problem in audio circuits, not just pc audio. Windows can often have same problem too. Turn speakers off before shutting down pc and turn on pc before turning speakers on.

Answer (score 2):

That's a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/373452
Do you have an HP laptop?

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and do:

Code:
gksudo gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave
Find this line:

```
INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=${INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE:-true}
```

and comment it out by putting a "#" in front of it like this:

```
# INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=${INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE:-true}
```

Just below this line you make a new line, like this:

```
INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false
```

So now you will have:

```
# INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=${INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE:-true}
INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false
```

Save the file (File > Save) and exit.

Reboot the computer.

The popping sound will be gone.

NOTE: If you for some reason need to undo the setting, just open the file again and remove the "#" from:

```
INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=${INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE:-true}
```

and delete this line:

```
INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false
```

Save the file.

Reboot.

http://gnometechblog.weebly.com/1/post/2012/03/fixing-popping-sound-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

I have Kubuntu 19.10 and had this loud popping problem.

[note: you need to be root for this].

Open file in console using: sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf [or, use Dolphin, open with Kate.]

Add the following line at the bottom of the page:

options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N

save and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

> The computer often seems to make beep noises or other sounds at
> various times, whether we want them or not. They come from various
> sources, and as such, you may be able to configure if or when they
> occur.
>
> Blacklisting the pcspkr module will prevent udev from loading it at
> boot:
>
> ```
> # echo "blacklist pcspkr" | tee /etc/modprobe.d/nobeep.conf
> ```

[PC speaker - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PC_speaker)

Answer (score -1):

You need  turn EAPD off in alsa driver.

http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Detailed_HDA_changes_v1.0.24_v1.0.25#HDA_Intel_driver

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.