# Popping explosive sound on reboot

Tags: sound, reboot, 17.04

I installed a fresh 17.04 install today on an Intel NUC 5i5RYK system. Everything was fine except that every time that it powers off or on (both reboot and shutdown), there is an extremely loud explosive sound that gets sent to the speakers. Very loud and feels like it will fry them.

I looked and saw that there was already a similar question ([Loud pop on shutdown/reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127737/loud-pop-on-shutdown-reboot)) that was answered for Ubuntu 12.04. However, the solution requires editing the `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave` which doesn't exist in my installation. All I see in the `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/` directory are `95hdparm-apm` and `anacron`. I read that the entire stack was changed since, so this may make sense, but I couldn't find any information on how to solve this in newer Ubuntu releases.

If it matters, the sound that is exploding is coming from the analog audio jack (not using the HDMI audio) and the sound card is `Realtek ALC283`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Anyone? Maybe it is a driver issue?