# Poping Loud noise when shutting down Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, noise, lg

I installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lg Gram laptop. Both systems seems to work. However, every now and then when I tried to shut down Ubuntu, the laptop can make an extremely loud beeping noise. Windows, on the other hand, never made any noise when I shut it down. Does anybody know what is going on?

I tried advices from [Loud pop on shutdown/reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127737/loud-pop-on-shutdown-reboot) but the problem still exist.

Comment: It's probably just a glitch of the audio driver. It doesn't happen in Windows because there you have proprietary tweaked drivers to account for specific implementations whereas in Ubuntu you're using something more "generic".

Comment: That information should be in the question itself, not in comments. Please [edit] to add that and also **everything else** you already tried. This avoids suggestions that you've tried and found not to work. That said, it may not have a solution but I'm sure it's something you can live with.